# Could someone explain what "compiling" in R is, and why it would speed up this code?

Tags: r, performance

I am working on some R code written by a previous student. The code is extremely computationally intensive, and for that reason he appears to have gone to great lengths to minimise the time it took in anyway possible.

One example is the following section:

```
# Now lets compile these functions, for a modest speed boost.
Sa <- cmpfun(Sa)
Sm <- cmpfun(Sm)
sa <- cmpfun(sa)
sm <- cmpfun(sm)
h <- cmpfun(h)
li <- cmpfun(lli)
ll <- cmpfun(ll)
```

He appears to have used the compiler package to do this.

I have never heard of compiling in R, and I am interested in what it does and why it would help speed up the code. I am having trouble finding material that would explain it for a novice like me.

Comment: check  `?cmpfun` for info.

Comment: Have a look a the [Byte Code Compiler](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/compiler/html/compile.html) from the compiler package.

Comment: Note that he writes "modest speed boost". There are often much better performance improvements possible by writing more efficient code, using better algorithms, implementing parts of the code in Rcpp, ...

Answer (score 4):

The **compiler** package has been part of R since version 2.130. Compiling R functions, results in a byte code version that may run faster. There are a number ways of compiling. All base R functions are compiled by default.

Compiling individual functions via `cmpfun`. Alternatively, you can call `enableJIT(3)` once and the R code is automatically compiled.

I've found compiling R code gives a modest, cost free speed boost - see [Efficient R programming](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/programming.html#the-byte-compiler) for a timed example.

It appears that byte compiling will be turned on by default in R 3.4.X